# Getting class level variables in a http.createServer requestListener

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have the following CoffeeScript code example:

```
class TestClass
    constructor: () ->
        @list = new Object()

    addToList: (key, value) ->
        @list[key] = value

    printList: () ->
        console.log("This is printed from printList:", @list)

    startHttp: () ->
        http = require("http")
        http.createServer(@printList).listen(8080)

test = new TestClass()
test.addToList("key", "value")
test.printList()
test.startHttp()
```

When I run the code, and make a HTTP request to 127.0.0.1:8080, I expect to get the following output:

> This is printed from printList: { key: 'value' }
>   This is printed from printList: { key: 'value' }

But I get the following instead:

> This is printed from printList: { key: 'value' }
>   This is printed from printList: undefined

Why is it the `printList` function can't access the `list` variable when it is called from the HTTP server?

I am using Node.js v0.6.1 and CoffeeScript v1.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printList: () =>
    console.log("This is printed from printList:", @list)
```

Use `=>` to bind the value of `this` to the function so it "works" as you expect.

**Disclaimer:** instances might break. Coffeescript is black magic for all I care.

What you really want to do is invoke the method on the correct object

```
that = this
http.createServer(->
  that.printList()
).listen 8080
```

Or in plain javascript.

```
var that = this;
http.createServer(function () {
  that.printList();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty new to object oriented programming in JavaScript, but that helped me out.